# Sublime Text 3 PHP UNIT

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, sublimetext3

In Sublime Text 3 PHP Unit doesn't work. Bundle has installed correctly but plugin is inactive. Has anyone resolved the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! I got this error: "cannot find file containing unit test" when i do a right click and select PHPUNIT. Any help with this ?

Comment: A PHPUnit plugin by me [phpunitkit](https://github.com/gerardroche/sublime-phpunit). It's designed to work out-of-the-box, especially when using composer. ST3 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest you to use this package which **isn't** available on Package Control:

[Sublime-PHPUnit](https://github.com/adamwathan/sublime-phpunit)

You need to pull this in manually by navigating to `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages` and paste it in. If you setup a few key binding, the workflow is very snappy. Watch this video for more info:

[Instant PHPUnit Feedback and Workflow](https://laracasts.com/series/professional-php-workflow-in-sublime-text/episodes/11)

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, there is a working ST3 version in the develop branch:

https://github.com/stuartherbert/sublime-phpunit/tree/develop

I got it to work by cloning the develop branch into my `{ST3}/Packages` folder and then restarting ST3.

At the time when I installed the plugin (a couple of months ago), the ST3 compatible version of sublime-phpunit was not available through Package Control, which is why I installed it with git.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! I got this error: "cannot find file containing unit test" when i do a right click and select PHPUNIT. Any help with this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try [PHPUnitKit](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PHPUnitKit), a Sublime Text plugin for running tests on different granularities. It's available on Package Control!

### FEATURES

- Run Test File
- Run Test Suite
- Run Nearest Test
- Run Last Test
- Fully customisable configuration
- Supports Composer installed PHPUnit
- Supports colour results, diffs, errors, etc.
- Jump to next and jump to previous failure

[image: PHPUnitKit]